# Laravel 5.3 Ajax Login Customize Credentials

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

I am able to login via Ajax in Laravel 5.3

This is easily accomplished by making a post request to the login route with the proper parameters.

However, for my application, I am designing two ways for a user to be logged in - via the traditional **email/password** combination that Laravel already supports, *and* via an **access code** that would be distributed and allow the possessor of said code to login without an email/password combination. There is no "registration" in my app, there is just different levels of authentication.

Anyway, in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth` I am editing the `AuthenticatesUsers.php` and understand that this function specifically handles the login attempts:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
        );
    }
```

My question is, how can I change the success of `attempt()` based on the content of the request?

In other words, if someone is sending an ajax access code it shouldn't be tested against an email/password combination, as it would obviously fail. Similarly, if they are sending an ajax with email/password parameters, it shouldn't be tested against the list of available access codes.

Am I on the right track? Where in Laravel can I go to make the `Auth::attempt()` contingent on request parameters?

Comment: I would not advice to edit the framework file. There is a complete section on manually authenticating a user un documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users. Also to check your ajax calls, look at line number `38` in `middleware/Authenticate.php` that should give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

I will not advice to edit a framework file. 
You should rather write a middleware to handle identification of the type of authentication user is requesting for, before sending it to the controller. In your middleware,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // check if the request has access_code
    $request->attributes->add(['using_access_code' => $request->has('access_code')]);
    return $next($request);
}
```

And in your controller, you can check for positive test on this request parameter that we newly added (you can of course do this inside controller directly, but I personally like middleware to handle this because there are chances that you may want to add more functionality)

In your controller, if `using_access_code` is false, proceed with `attempt()` login, else, retrieve the user using `access_code` and manually authenticate the user using `Auth::login($user)`. Let me know if you are unclear.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with middle-ware solutions. Is there an alternative?